# Unable to create ca certificate Lets Encrypt via PuTTY

Tags: ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

As mentioned above I'm getting error generating certificate from Lets encrypt for subdomain. Using Chrome tried www, http://www.subdomain www.subdomain.
Here is error I'm getting

```
fzcpnl49094m6oe7p2@a04pm945 [~]$ acme.sh   **--issue -d subdomain.domain.com -d subdomain.domain.com  -w /home/fzcpnpm945/public_html**
       subdomain.domain.com:Verify error:IPADRESS: Invalid response from http://subdomain.domain.com/.well-known/acme -challenge/rsv-gC-4XNqhH3QE7zd-JCox6A4CYVRRgVgYU3Jeaqs: 404
  Error Loading request extension section v3_req
 139755839661896:error:220A4076:X509 V3 routines:A2I_GENERAL_NAME:bad ip address: v3_alt.c:484:value=http://www.subdomain.domain.com
 139755839661896:error:22098080:X509 V3 routines:X509V3_EXT_nconf:error in extens ion:v3_conf.c:93:name=subjectAltName, value=IP:http://www.subdomain.domain .com,IP:http://www.subdomain.domain.com
  Create CSR error.
 Pending, The CA is processing your order, please  just wait. (1/30)
 www.subdomain.domain.com:Verify error:DNS p roblem: NXDOMAIN looking up A for www.subdomain.domain.com - check that a  DNS record exists for this domain; DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up AAAA for www .subdomain.domain.com - check that a DNS record exists for this domain
 Multi domain='DNS:www.subdomain.domain.com/ ,DNS:www.subdomain.domain.com/'
  Getting domain auth token for each domain
  Create new order error. Le_OrderFinalize not foun d. {
   "type": "urn:ietf:params:acme:error:rejectedIdentifier",
   "detail": "Error creating new order :: Cannot issue for \"www.subdomain.domain.com/\": Domain name contains an invalid character",
   "status": 400
 }
```

Comment: It seems that the error message is quite explicit in what you need to do and investigate:  *`DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up A for www.subdomain.domain.com - check that a  DNS record exists for this domain;`*

Comment: @diya yes it does exit for subdomain.domain.com  a records for subdomain

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. You need to mention complete path of directory including subdomain folder